# How can I change the time signature to make the score easier to read?

Tags: sheet-music, time-signatures, transcription

I'm trying to transcribe a pop song.

I'm fairly sure that the time signature is 2/4 since it has a *ONE two ONE two*, feel like a march.

My problem is that it's a fast song and contains so many 32th notes that it's difficult to read.

Is there any equivalency to 2/4 that I can use to make the score easier to read?

Comment: If it's a pop song it's likely in 4/4 since basically every pop song ever is in 4/4 but I guess one could argue that 2/4 is almost the same thing. Regardless, nonpop's answer is correct but the same thing is achieved by writing in 2/2, switching it to 2/4, and then saying the tempo is twice as fast. I don't see any reason it couldn't be moved to 4/4 either. The time signature is a matter of convenience, literally any of them could be used.

Comment: Yes. ONE two ONE two in a pop song is 4/4. The primary thing you can do to make a score easier to read is put it in common time, unless it simply cannot be written in common time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about 2/2 (alla breve)? This also goes in two, but the pulse is a half-note so you can write your 32nds as 16ths, which should be readable. Nowadays alla breve is also usually associated with a quick tempo so to an experienced musician it should look right.